# Google Plus Sign in From other UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, google-plus

when i signin in the Main ViewController in my Case ViewController.m every think works fine

with same code i sign in on other UIViewController  login.m

when i close the app and run again trysilentauthentication will return false always

its lookalike nothing saved

i use this code to sign in login.m :

```
signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
signIn.clientID = kClientId;
signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];
signIn.delegate = self;
[signIn authenticate];
```

and i check in ViewController.m :

```
if ([signIn trySilentAuthentication]) {
    NSLog(@"trySilentAuthentication Return True");
}else {
    NSLog(@"trySilentAuthentication Return False");
}
```

and i sign out in login.m using :

```
- (IBAction)signOut:(id)sender {

[self ClearUserData];
[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
[self refreshInterfaceBasedOnSignIn];
```

}

is it something With Delegate ?